# Changing the columns titles on a GridView if I set the datasource on codebehind?

Tags: asp.net

How do I set the GridView Category Columns Titles manually if I'm databinding manually?

```
namespace Workforce
{
    public partial class WebForm1 : System.Web.UI.Page
    {
        protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

            var s = Work.DataLayer.Connection("test");

            var x = Work.DataLayer.GetCourseList(s);
            GridView1.DataSource = x;
            GridView1.DataBind();

        }
    }
}
```

In the design view, there is a data source id which i'm not using.

Comment: Probably try the row data binding event of gridview.

Answer (score 0):

How about this

```
GridView1.HeaderRow.Cells[0].Text = "New Header";
```

Answer (score 0):

Like @Rahul stated, you want to do this in the [RowDataBound](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.gridview.rowdatabound(v=vs.110).aspx) event

```
protected void GridView1_RowDataBound(object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.Header)
    {
        e.Row.Cells[0].Text = "Your Better Column Header";
    }
}
```

And repeat for each row header you want to modify, ensuring you have used the correct ordinal number.

Comment: My GridView1 is actually bound to a list of Courses. Should I be using dataset or datadaptertable isntead?

Comment: If I understand your question correctly, it shouldn't matter. It's the binding event you're after, which has nothing to do with the type being bound (List, DataTable, etc).